# Is there a way to retrieve multiple files (files-urls) through the iOS share sheet (Activity View) without using the iOS share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, share-extension, ios-sharesheet

I wanted to implement a feature that allows the sharing of multiple files simultaneously to my app from an external app like Files.

In my ApplicationDelegate file, I provided the following method, which currently only retrieves a single file URL from the share sheet, even when multiple files were selected in the Files app:

```objc
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    return [self handleSharedURL:url options:options];
}
```

I'm curious to know if there is a way to obtain multiple file URLs without relying on a share extension. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.